# Kartik's datecontrol is not providing correct date

Tags: datepicker, yii2

kartik date control is not setting the date. If a date of tuesday and thursday is selected; If I check the value of the hidden input field they are set to false when one of these two days is selected. Please!!!! I need your help I am stuck.
The version is dev-master that I dowloaded one month ago. 
[image: Image showing how it is reacting]

Here is how I configured the Extension:
         'datecontrol' =>  [
            'class' => 'kartik\datecontrol\Module',

```
        // format settings for displaying each date attribute (ICU format example)
        'displaySettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => 'php:D d-M-Y',
            Module::FORMAT_TIME => 'php:H:i:s',
            Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'php:D d-M-Y H:i:s', 
        ],

        // format settings for saving each date attribute (PHP format example)
        'saveSettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => 'php:Y-m-d', 
            Module::FORMAT_TIME => 'php:H:i:s',
            Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s',
        ],

        // set your display timezone
//        'displayTimezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',

        // set your timezone for date saved to db
//        'saveTimezone' => 'UTC',

        // automatically use kartik\widgets for each of the above formats
        'autoWidget' => true,

        // default settings for each widget from kartik\widgets used when autoWidget is true
        'autoWidgetSettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => ['type'=>2, 'pluginOptions'=>['autoclose'=>true]], // example
            Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => [], // setup if needed
            Module::FORMAT_TIME => [], // setup if needed
        ],

        // custom widget settings that will be used to render the date input instead of kartik\widgets,
        // this will be used when autoWidget is set to false at module or widget level.
        'widgetSettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => [
                'class' => 'yii\jui\DatePicker', // example
                'options' => [
                    'dateFormat' => 'php:d-M-Y',
                    'options' => ['class'=>'form-control'],
                ]
            ]
        ]
        // other settings
    ]
```

Here is what is in my view:

```
    <?=$form->field($model, 'dated')->widget(DateControl::classname(), [
    'type'=>DateControl::FORMAT_DATE,
    'language'=>Yii::$app->language,
    'ajaxConversion'=>false,
    'options' => [
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'autoclose' => true
        ]
    ]
])?>
```

Comment: Please Add  more detail how you are applying the datacontrol.

Comment: @Anamika Shrivastava I've added more details

Comment: its working fine. Add your view file code how you are trying to add this field

Comment: @Anamika Shrivastava I've put the view code

Comment: Enable timezone setting in web.php config fie   `'displayTimezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',

        // set your timezone for date saved to db
        'saveTimezone' => 'UTC',` and set `'ajaxConversion'=>true,` in view  file.

Comment: @Anamika Shrivastava  the problem is I would not like to convert the date; I just want the date of the user to be save in the database as it is given by him; so what I mean is it the user said january 1 2016 it must be saved and displayed as that without any timezoneinfluence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is ;

I Enable timezone setting in web.php config fie

```
'displayTimezone' => 'UTC', 
 'saveTimezone' => 'UTC',
```

and set

```
 'ajaxConversion'=>true,
```

so As Mysql does not convert the date and time datatype data to client timezone;  the date will not influenced by the timezone when being displayed.